# JavaScript/<text area >

Tags: javascript

```
alert("...");

var values = "value1
valu2part1 value2part2 
value3
valu4";
alert(values);
```

I am assigning:

```
var values = "<%=Model.Values%>";
```

These values are stored in a database.  The values are entered through a textarea
and in the database each line is seperated by `\t\r`.

When I take this to a JavaScript variable using:

```
var values = "<%=Model.Values%>";
```

I am getting some thing like:

```
var values = "value1
valu2part1 value2part2
value3
valu4";
```

But this is anerror.  What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = "<%=Model.Values%>";
```

This is unsafe. Not only will it fail when there are newlines in the string (as JavaScript string literals cannot span multiple lines), it's also possible for a `"` in the value to end the string prematurely. If the value contains user-submitted data, that's a script-injection security hole (XSS).

To create JS literal syntax use a JSON serialiser. For example with [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var values= <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Values) %>;
```

or eg [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/13099) if you're on older .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your new lines with escape sequences (`\n`) before outputting your string to the JS.